# Angular 17 in iOS Devices with v15.2 or older problem in routing-outlets

Tags: router-outlet, angular17, ios15.2, ios-15.4

Hi on Angular 17 all iOS devices with v15.2 or older, the routing outlet(the nested outlets which we used to pop up a modal, aka."/(modal:signin)") stopped working.

When I create many simulations of different versions of iOS I catch that on v15.4 it works fine, but everything older NOT. Try to find and understand the iOS documentation for the release, but nothing there help me to fix my problem. There were two C++ libraries that they updated, but I didn't figure out how they could help me with my problem. When I run the simulation on my MAC to have a console for iPad for example it shows an error that says "commands.at(-1)" is undefined. This code is in the node_modules in routing and it appears in many places. Also, I found that in some places they make a check about the "commands.length" if it > 0, which probably could fix my problem, but this can not be a solution to my problem so I am searching for another one. If someone experiences such a problem with Angular 17 on older iOS devices?
P.S. Regular routing is working. example [routerLink]="/home", also our application is standAlone without modules.
P.S. the error is NG04004 {outlets:{}} has to be the last command it is in the file: node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2022/router.mjs

Comment: Until now the only answer is that the version is too old to be supported by Angular, bc they support the last 2 versions which at that moment are 16 and 17. However, I can not leave all the users who are using an older iOS version which means that I have to rework routing or use MatDialog.  Is that really my only choice?